# Check jsch connection on background?

Tags: java, android, jsch

I've created an android that controls my raspberry pi with ssh. I'm currently using the jsch library for the connection. I want to create a background task that checks the connection repeatedly if it's still connected. I know session.isConnected() returns a boolean but I don't know how I can create a background task which update a textview when the connection drops.